# How to force R to update png file creation date?

Tags: r

I'm using this code to create a .png from of my plots:

```
png(filename="H:/plot.png", width=650, height=875, units="px", res=100)
grobz <- lapply(list(1.plot, 2.plot, 3.plot, 4.plot), ggplotGrob)
grobz.plot <- arrangeGrob( grobs = list(rbind(grobz[[1]], grobz[[2]], grobz[[3]], grobz[[4]], size = "last")), ncol = 1)
grid.draw(grobz.plot)
dev.off()
```

When I delete the image file and re-run my code, the .png file still has the old file creation date.

What do I need to add in the code or R settings to force R to make the file with the current/updated date?

Answer (score 0):

maybe '[Sys.setFileTime(path, time)](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.0/topics/Sys.setFileTime)' can help
Although there should be a more sophisticated way to update a write/save time than this

Answer (score 0):

You can set one variable name to update with `Sys.time()`

```
time <- Sys.time()
#time <- as.Date(Sys.time()) # if you need only the date
path <- "~/somepath/"
path_name <- paste0(path, time, ".png") # the exact location with file name
png(filename=path_name , width=650, height=875, units="px", res=100)
# ...
```

Comment: I can't change the path or file name because both are used for additional work. I was hoping to just change the file attribute somehow, unless it's possibly a Windows OS problem?

Comment: Forgive me if don't undestand completely, but why not using different variables? One that is fixed and the other that changes with time.

Comment: The image files are referenced by name in other scripts, so names that change over time would break the process.